# SSRS different first page header

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting

I need a custom first page header in ssrs. I was trying to do it with custom visibility through expression. It works in reportviewer, but when exporting to word or pdf, visibility is not persisted and always shows first page header.

Answer (score 4):

- If you already have a normal page header that you want to appear on all subsequent pages except the first, then set the PrintOnFirstPage property of the Page Header to be False in the Properties window.
- Add your custom first page header layout to the top of the report Body - ie. above everything else that appears in the report Body, but below the Page Header section (if enabled).

Comment: Bullet 1 doesn't apply because I still need custom 1st page header, not hidden. Concerning bullet two - when I'm going to export to .doc, the header is not going to appear in a header of document. Any fix for that?

Comment: I like this solution.  I need a very big header on my first page, but then only a small piece of data on each subsequent page's header.  So, by simply moving my detailed header to the top of the body, using the header space with the small amount of data, and disabling the header on the first page I believe I can achieve what I need.  Thanks Mark - this is a very good idea.